# Why html attribute <img loading="lazy" not working while transform translate 1px out of the top of a overflow container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to transform image in overflow container avoid of showing out of bounds image.
Delete green area and show a bigger image to user.
[image]

But lazy image is not visible automatically as expected while scrolling, they are not fetched.
[image]
I tried to reproduce this Bug to a simple Demo here.

```
<div style={{
    overflow:'hidden',
}} className=''>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.png" style={{
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        transform:'translate(0,-1px)',
    }} loading='lazy' alt="" />
</div>
```

Notice each of **overflow:'hidden', verticalAlign: 'top',  transform:'translate(0,-1px)', loading='lazy'** are important in this case, they combine and then course the Bug.

Complete Demo here. google image can't loading as lazy.

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-minsky-v131fs?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but would you try to add this css?

```
.img { position: absolute; margin: 0; padding: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; }
```

Comment: I had tried. It's useless .

:(

Comment: Ok. i'm sorry for that. Then could you try to move the style in your external css? It's look like [This](https://i.imgur.com/3HcbHb2.png) then add more in your css to your desired position or orientation of the image.

Comment: Inline style and external css effect the same.
I tried in https://bl9gxj.csb.app/ , they both load image fail.
You can fork https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-minsky-v131fs?file=/src/App.js and give a success example.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm having a trouble to understand the problem. Is it the image? or the whitespace in every corner?

Comment: While image is lazy loaded successfully , you will see a google icon in the bottom. Otherwise it load failed.